# Good cloud solution for simple PHP files?

Tags: php, cloud

OK so I've used amazon CDN for awhile now and love it for hosting html/media/javascript. But I've run into a few things I really need php for - but of course since that's server side amazon CDN can't do it.

Ideally I want a solution that I can just upload a php file into and it works just like I can for HTML/Java for AmazonCDN.

What would you guys suggest? Can it be this easy or is it gonna have to be more complicated then that for PHP?

Comment: Are you looking for a webhost? I don't like dreamhost, but dangggg they are cheap.

Comment: But realistically speaking, a CDN is for serving static files, not rendering dynamic ones.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Amazon for your CDN, you may want to consider trying their EC2 instances to keep everything under the same roof.  I use them, and have had really good luck with it.  I tend to build my EC2 instances from the ground up, but there is a large repository of community images that you could use.  I'm sure that there is a simple php webserver image out there.

You could also use a shared hosting environment like dreamhost, media temple (gs) or the like.   If you are using a CDN because of high traffic though, than those services may not cut it.

Also, my $0.02:
If you are deploying php applications, a drag and drop/upload and forget it solution may be nice and easy, but could cause you headaches down the road.  If your application is something other than trivial, it would be prudent to learn how to set up a web server from scratch.  That being said, I don't know what you are doing, so your solution may be perfect for your application.

hth